# How could I use more commands in the if/else statement in Python?

Tags: python

I wanted to apply more than 1 command under the if/else statement in a simple Python program.
Python has the following error message: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level.
I used VSCode to apply this program.

How could I use more commands in the same if/else statement?
I tried to run the following program, but it did not work properly, because of identation problem:

```
colourlist = ['blue', 'red', 'white', 'black', 'green', 'yellow', 'brown', 'red', 'white', 'grey']

colour = input('Give me a colour!\t')

if colour in colourlist:
    print('The colour you have given is in the list'+ str(colourlist.count(colour)) +' time/s.')
else:
    colourlist.append(colour)
        print('The given colour is not in the list.')
print('The colours of the list:')
for colour in colourlist:
    print(colour, end=', ')
```

Comment: The line `print('The given colour is not in the list.')` is too far indented - pull it back to match the `colourlist.append(colour)` above it.

Comment: In python, a block is defined by how much indentation there is behind it. you have too much indention for `print('The given colour is not in the list.')`. if it is supposed to be in `else` it should have the same amount of indentation as  `colourlist.append(colour)`

Comment: A tip to be more Pythonic: instead of repeatedly counting each color with `str(colourlist.count(colour))`, more Pythonic to declare `cnt = collections.Counter(colour)`, that gives you a Counter object whose keys will be colours and values will be counts. And you don't need to manually concatenate a clunky `str()` call, look into f-strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line number 9 is indented with 8 spaces, that's not necessary since you don't have a new block of code.

To run new commands, just remove the unnecessary blank spaces from that line and it should work just fine. Your code should look something like this

```
colourlist = ['blue', 'red', 'white', 'black', 'green', 'yellow', 'brown', 'red', 'white', 'grey']

colour = input('Give me a colour!\t')

if colour in colourlist:
    print('The colour you have given is in the list'+ str(colourlist.count(colour)) +' time/s.')
else:
    colourlist.append(colour)
        # print('The given colour is not in the list.') -- OLD PRINT STATEMENT
    print('The given colour is not in the list.')
        
print('The colours of the list:')
for colour in colourlist:
    print(colour, end=', ')
```

Python cares about your code indentation, so just indent your code when you have a new block of code, such as: `while, for, if`...

To use more commands in the if/else statement you just need to write your code respecting the if/else block indentation